# Sql select rows containing part of string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to write a comparation procedure (t-sql) for site seo.

I have a table with field 'url' (nvarchar()) that contain a part of site url's.
Ex: '*mysyte.com/?id=2*'. Also this table for each url contains metadata, that i need to extract.

The main problem is that full url on site looks like '*mysyte.com/?id=2&region=0&page=1*', and i just need to ignore everething, except url in table:

I mean: 'mysyte.com/?id=2' => is a part of 'mysyte.com/?id=2&region=0&page=1'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE URL = LEFT('mysyte.com/?id=2&region=0&page=1', LEN(URL))
```

Or use CHARINDEX
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258228(v=SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 86):

You can use the LIKE operator to compare the content of a T-SQL string, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [field] LIKE '%stringtosearchfor%'
```

The percent character '%' is a wild card- in this case it says return any records where [field] *at least* contains the value "stringtosearchfor".

Comment: To search for a string that begins with a certain prefix, you can do LIKE 'prefix%'

Comment: What about if the haystack may or may not start with the needle? Any difference then?

Answer (score 6):

you can use `CHARINDEX` in t-sql.

`select * from table where CHARINDEX(url, 'http://url.com/url?url...') > 0`