# Searching a string for a partial match against a database

Tags: database, string, pattern-matching, field, partial

I have a string "TRTGREENTE" and I also have the following values in a db
1. "BlUE"
2. "WHITE"
3. "GREEN"
n. "..."
+1 "..."

Going through every single value in the db and doing a partial match is not the solution I Want... I remember creating a sequencing (reverse) protein synthesis algorithm for something like this, but I would have to go find my old documents (from college).,

besides coding a synthesis algorithm.

Can someone suggest an algorithm that can do this efficiently? Would using a nosql db over a MSSQL db solve this easier?

It looks like something that does fuzzy matching would be needed for this; but the question I have is., how do you fuzzy match against a database and get the database value

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621586/sql-select-rows-containing-part-of-string

Comment: ling, how would you apply that to this? at one end you have an expression that has a partial string match to values in the other expression (table); the partial string that matches a value or values in the table could be anywhere in the string i.e. XXXSTRINGX, or XSTRINGXXXXXX, and the table could have a million rows and one of those is STRING.

Comment: Maybe this example helps., goto google maps., type in ASDASDCALIFORNIAASDASD it gives you a "did you mean ASDASD CALIFORNIA ASDASD"; in my case, I would have CALIFORNIA in the table somewhere and would dump the other two non-matching words